# How can I prevent Desktop Users from connecting to new wireless networks?

Tags: wireless, security

I have a created a wireless connection from the main admin account and checked the box saying "Available to all users", everything is working correctly. I only need to prevent the Desktop Users from switching the connection to another one.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: So you would like them to only be able to use the wireless connection that you have given them?

Answer (score 1):

You can kill **nm-applet** (the thing in the bar at the top that let's you choose the network settings), and use **iwconfig** to choose the wireless network, like this (assuming your wireless NIC is **wlan0**):

```
$ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

This will display all available wireless networks.

```
$ sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid "MyWirelessNetwork"
```

This will try to connect to the wireless network with SSID "MyWirelessNetwork"

```
$ sudo dhclient wlan0
```

This will get an IP from the DHCP server.

Since the above commands require **sudo** powers, regular users will not be able to change the wireless settings.

If you choose, you could remove the **nm-applet** all together by removing the package **network-manager-gnome**